# All 3 Starters in Kalos?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How do you get all 3 in the Pokemon X and Y Games? I have X and I've beaten the game, however I would like to get all 3 starters without using any cheats at all. I picked Fennekin as my starter and I have "Chester" (Chespin) that was given to me by Shauna. I would really appreciate it if someone told me how to get Froakie legitamately.

Answer (score 6):

You can only get two of the starter Pokemon in one game of X or Y. The one you pick and the one given to you by Shauna.

To get the third, trade with someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the Global Trade Service (GTS) and request Froakie and see what people are trading for it.

You can also just try your luck with the Wonder Trade - you put up a Pokémon and it will get automatically traded with another random Pokémon.

Answer (score 1):

Froakie was pretty common on *Wonder Trade*, before the ORAS release. Now there are a lot of junk wild Pokemon, but you should get one easily anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can only obtain two of three starter Pokemon in X and Y without connecting to the Internet. To obtain the third, there are a few different ways to do so:

- Trading with a friend, acquaintance, or passerby on PSS. In your message, you can say something like, "LF: Froakie" LF is a common way of saying "looking for"
- Depositing a Pokemon on the GTS and requesting a Froakie. To make this easier, change your message to "need for Dex". Many people are nice enough to give Pokemon if you need it for the Dex
- Wondertrading. Many people wondertrade their Froakies here. However, this is not guaranteed since people just trade whatever they want.
- Friend Safari. If any of your friends have a water friend safari, try looking for one of Froakie's evolutions. You can breed them to obtain a Froakie.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could try a water friend safari, might take time though (sometimes's it froakie's second evolution)